# How to customize the cursor on the SortableJS plugin when drag an item

Tags: javascript, plugins, sortablejs

I need help please ! :D
I can't find how to change the cursor when dragging with the "SortableJS" plugin ([SortableJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable)).

I use the plugin without react, the basic one in a table to move the rows.

Thanks in advance ! :D

Comment: check this issue: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/issues/246, they present some solutions

Comment: Ah thanks ! :D
This option (forceFallback: true) change all ! ;)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

For the ones that fall here from G like me, something like this will do it:

```js
var grid = document.getElementById('grid');
new Sortable(grid, {
    animation: 150,
    swap: true,
    swapThreshold: 0.65,
    ghostClass: 'dragFrom',
    swapClass: 'dragTo',
    forceFallback: true, // This is it!
    onChoose: function(e) {
        e.target.classList.add('grabbing');
    },
    onUnchoose: function(e) {
        e.target.classList.remove('grabbing');
    },
    onStart: function(e) {
        e.target.classList.add('grabbing');
    },
    onEnd: function(e) {
        e.target.classList.remove('grabbing');
    },
  onMove: function(e) {
        e.target.classList.add('grabbing');
    },
});
```

```css
.grabbing * {
    cursor: grabbing !important;
}
.grid {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.grid-square {
  margin:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px rgb(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align: center;
    cursor: grab;
  padding-top:35px;
  width:75px;
  height:50px;
}
.grid-square:active {
    cursor: grabbing!important;/* fighting on all fronts */
}
.dragFrom{
    background-color: #48b4e6!important;
}

.dragTo {
    background-color: #30ec5f!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.15.0/Sortable.min.js"></script>
 
<div id="grid">
    <div class="grid-square">1</div>
    <div class="grid-square">2</div>
    <div class="grid-square">3</div>
    <div class="grid-square">4</div>
    <div class="grid-square">5</div>
    <div class="grid-square">6</div>
</div>
```

The `forceFallback: true,` line is the key to bypass the [issue](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/issues/246) pointed by Arthur in his comment to the question post.

The `onChoose`, `onUnchoose`, `onStart`, `onEnd` and most CSS are my dirty solution after testing some times. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SortableJS automatically adds `.sortable-chosen` class to the item that's being moved.

You just need a bit of CSS, like so:

```
.sortable-chosen {
    cursor: grabbing !important;
}
```

Hope this helps!